# git workflow for multi client web development

Tags: git, workflow, git-flow

I'm having a hard time figuring out a good workflow for the git development process in an agency.

I want to use git flow as it seems to fit our situation pretty good. 
Here's my problem with this approach :

We start developing feature a and feature b. Both inside individual feature branches. 
When work on the features is done, they get merged in develop. 
Now the client responsible for the QA takes a look at a test server which has the develop branch checked out.

The client decides: feature b can go live, feature a needs to be worked on again.

How can we roll back the changes done by feature a development and deploy feature b?

I also thought about having the QA on the individual feature branches before merging them to develop. 
But I don't know if that's a good way of dealing with this problem

Any best practices for such problems?

Answer (score 0):

Branch develop usually does not go live as is.

Features from develop are being merged or (in your particular case) cherry-picked in production branch.

Scheme I've been succesfully following for more then a year now:

- master - development branch, no client access (worth noticing - tiny feature requests and minor bugfixes are done right in master without feature branches; it might not be your case)
- stage - staging branch, client QA, derives from master
- production - live app releases